# Dynamically call classes from list of their names in Flutter

Tags: class, dart, flutter

I have a list of my defined widget names in flutter. Let's say they are ['widget_1', 'widget_2'] etc. defined in a separate file custom_widget.dart. All the widgets take the same argument, let's say 'widget_argument'. I want to call these widgets dynamically in a loop using their names along with their arguments in Flutter. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You'll need to have a function that manually constructs the corresponding widgets from their names.  Unfortunately, you currently can't use constructors as "tear-offs", which would make it slightly simpler.

Comment: okay, I see. Thanks for the information.